# Orocrm in Docker in Azure

Tags: azure, dockerfile, orocrm

I would like to deploy Orocrm community edition in Azure in web service or Azure docker container and Azure MySQL. I'm looking for good working documentation

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The application requires a lot of services. At least database (mysql), web server (nginx), php interpreter (php-fpm), consumer services, websockets, etc.. In the docker paradigm, these should be separate containers. The documentation describes a typical setup, what should be done from the application side. If you want some non-standard installation, you will have to adapt it yourself.
We are currently developing the ability to run in containerized environments. But there are a lot of them and there will not be a single approach. And it's hard to meet all the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the great information. So, what's the most modern and scalable yet non-customized approach to host in the cloud? Is there good documentation for using app service and cloud mysql?